PySpark encoding when writing CSV
I am trying to convert parquet files to CSV files using Spark in Glue in AWS (for exporting data). I need to either convert them to ISO-8859-1, or ANSI. However, when I am running this code it still writes as UTF-8
 df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)

df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").option("header", "true").csv(tmp_s3_path)

The files are still written in UTF-8. I had the same result when trying cp1252. However, when I changed to UTF-16 as follow, it did actually write in UTF-16
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("encoding", "UTF-16").option("header", "true").csv(tmp_s3_path)

Any ideas why ISO-8859-1 or cp1252 isnt working? The CSV file in question contains only valid characters for all of these encodings
I am using AWS Glue V 4.0 - which supports Spark 3.3

What do you see that leads you to believe they're written in UTF-8? (since ISO-8859-1 is a subset of UTF-8 and you claim that there are only valid characters in the source data)

@kdgregory when I open my files in VSCode/Notepad/Notepad++ I see them as UTF-8. And I see my UTF-16 experiment as UTF-16. Also I have the same issue with ANSI, Windows 1252

That seems to be an issue with how VSCode/Notepad/Notepad++ loads the file, not necessarily with how it's written. I suggest that you verify that the file just contains valid characters and no prologue, and if so ignore what your editor is telling you.

@kdgregory  ISO-8859-1 is not a subset of UTF-8 …

You are correct; I was thinking US-ASCII, based on the OP's comment of "ANSI". However, I still think that the most likely issue is that the editor is reporting UTF-8 as a default, and the OP should examine the file to verify that it does not contain UTF-8 byte sequences. If there are characters with the high bit set, then I would be very surprised if all of those characters managed to be valid UTF-8 byte sequences, and would expect the editor to flag that (but I don't use MS editors, so maybe it just ignores them).
